# “Where's the servant whose business it is to answer the door?”

Tags: relative-clauses

> “Where's the servant whose business it is to answer the door?"

I just read this in Through the Looking Glass. If I said that sentence, I would have said "business is". Why is the 'it' necessary? Is this because this book is 200-years old? Can one still say like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without "it", the meaning is that the servant has a door-opening enterprise, instead of meaning that one of the servant's responsibilities is to open the door.  I see no change in how this is expressed since Carroll's time.

Comment: Well, I think one would be more likely to say "... whose job it is ..." today.

Comment: I can memorise this, but I do not understand it. Could you explain why putting 'it' makes that difference?

Comment: With the hint from the first comment, I have found a similar question already has been answered. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35759/a-guy-whose-job-is-to-vs-a-guy-whose-job-it-is-to

Comment: @HotLicks I think a lot of people would still say 'business' nowadays. It probably derives from the expressions *mind your own business*, *is it any of your business?* etc. They perpetuate a particular sense of the word *business* which is probably being invoked in this OP example.